# Aligning raster perfectly with feature using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, features, rasterization

I have a feature layer with 1000x1000m polygons that are seamlessly glued together. From this layer I want to create a raster with 25x25m cells as basis for further raster operations.
I'm using ArcMap > Tools > **Polygon to Raster** to do so, with cell size 25 and no other settings (no snap raster, no specified processing extent etc). The feature layer is in a metric projection (LV95).

I assumed since 1000 divides cleanly by 25, that the raster would align perfectly with the borders of the polygons, however the raster is not aligned (see below).

**What can I do to snap the Raster directly to the edges of the polygons (or to avoid ambiguity one reference polygon)?**

[image: the raster is not aligned with the feature]